# Why the camera is never looking forward direction and always looking down?

Tags: unity, c#

While the camera(transform) is moving between the waypoints I want that according to the CameraViewMode enum selected option is the direction the camera will look at.

The BirdsEye mode is always the view mode even if I select the Forward.
I found that I can't change the camera rotation while it's moving between the waypoints , not sure if it's because there are so many waypoints and they are very close to each other less then 1 distance or becaue I want the camera rotating facing to the next waypoint each time.

This how it is now , the camera is looking at the waypoints from up to down:
This is what I count as the BirdsEye view mode:

[image: BirdsEye view mode]

The forward view mode should be when the blue axis will be forward and not down.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public enum CameraViewMode
{
    BirdsEye,
    Forward
}

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public LayerMask terrainLayer;
    [GapRange(0, 100, GapDisplayMode.Floats)]
    public float gap = 0f;
    public float cameraMoveSpeed = 5f;
    public float zoomSpeed = 5f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public List<Transform> wayPoints = new List<Transform>();
    public float waypointsMovementSpeed = 5f;
    public float waypointsRotationSpeed = 5f;
    public float cameraHeightOffset = 2f;
    public CameraViewMode viewMode = CameraViewMode.BirdsEye;

    private Vector3 lastCubePosition;
    private bool isDragging = false;
    private int currentWaypointIndex = 0;
    private bool isMoving = false;
    private bool isRotating = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleCameraMovement();
        HandleCameraRotation();

        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        HandleRuntimeInput(mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2)) // Middle mouse button pressed
        {
            isMoving = true; // Start moving towards waypoints
        }

        if (isMoving)
        {
            MoveTowardsWaypoint();
        }
    }

    void MoveTowardsWaypoint()
    {
        if (currentWaypointIndex >= wayPoints.Count)
        {
            isMoving = false; // Reached all waypoints, stop moving
            return;
        }

        // Get the current waypoint position and rotation
        Vector3 targetPosition = wayPoints[currentWaypointIndex].position;

        if (!isRotating && currentWaypointIndex == 0)
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation;
            if (viewMode == CameraViewMode.BirdsEye)
            {
                targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.down, Vector3.up);
            }
            else
            {
                targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position, Vector3.up);
            }

            // Rotate towards the desired direction
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            if (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation) < 0.01f)
            {
                isRotating = true; // Finished rotating, start moving towards the first waypoint
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position, Vector3.up);

            // Calculate the target camera position with height offset
            Vector3 targetCameraPosition = targetPosition + Vector3.up * cameraHeightOffset;

            // Move towards the target camera position
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetCameraPosition, waypointsMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // Rotate towards the waypoint rotation
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, waypointsRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // Check if reached the current waypoint
            if (transform.position == targetCameraPosition)
            {
                currentWaypointIndex++; // Move to the next waypoint
                isRotating = false; // Reset the rotation flag
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleRuntimeInput(Vector3 mousePosition)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isDragging = true;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity, terrainLayer))
            {
                lastCubePosition = hitInfo.point;
                GenerateCube(lastCubePosition);
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isDragging = false;
        }
        else if (isDragging && gap > 0f)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity, terrainLayer))
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(hitInfo.point, lastCubePosition) >= gap)
                {
                    GenerateCubesBetween(lastCubePosition, hitInfo.point);
                    lastCubePosition = hitInfo.point;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateCube(Vector3 position)
    {
        float terrainHeight = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(position);
        Vector3 cubePosition = new Vector3(position.x, terrainHeight, position.z);
        GameObject go = Instantiate(cubePrefab, cubePosition, Quaternion.identity);
        wayPoints.Add(go.transform);
    }

    private void GenerateCubesBetween(Vector3 start, Vector3 end)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(start, end);
        int numCubes = Mathf.RoundToInt(distance / gap);

        Vector3 direction = (end - start).normalized;
        float stepSize = distance / numCubes;

        for (int i = 0; i < numCubes; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position = start + direction * (i * stepSize);
            GenerateCube(position);
        }
    }

    private void HandleCameraMovement()
    {
        // Get the horizontal and vertical input
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Convert input to world space relative to the camera's rotation
        Vector3 moveDirection = (horizontalInput * transform.right + verticalInput * transform.forward).normalized;

        // Apply movement
        transform.position += moveDirection * cameraMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void HandleCameraRotation()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            float rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed;
            float rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed;

            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationX, Space.World);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, -rotationY, Space.Self);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of code here not directly related to the camera rotation issue. You may get better answers, faster, if you reduce this code to a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: the smallest code that reproduces the problem you want to fix.

Comment: By the way, if you want to create some dramatic camera movements, then [the Cinemachine package](https://unity.com/unity/features/editor/art-and-design/cinemachine) might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as intended, but your scene is not set up well.

`MoveTowardsWaypoint()` does two things depending on the current state:

- If `isRotating` is `false` and `currentWaypointIndex` is `0`, rotate the camera. (Huh? You rotate the camera when `isRotating` is false?)
- Otherwise, move the camera until it is directly above the waypoint while looking directly at the waypoint, then target the next waypoint.

You have created far too many waypoints too close together, so the next waypoint is always (almost) directly underneath the camera, so the camera is always looking down.

You should delete most of your waypoints; this will improve performance and make the camera behave the way you want it to.